# ASP NET CORE conectar a base de datos local por ConnectionString

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core

Hola amigos estoy tratando de conectarme a una BD local con **MSSMS** y **ASPNET CORE** , bueno total que ya logré conectarme y todo. Naturalmente quiero hacer un query, pero no puedo conectarme a la bd para hacer el mismo. Me conecté manualmente con el asistente de SQL y me generó una **Connection String**, como podemos ver aquí.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

metí el **Connection string** a mis variables de entorno y si la estoy recibiendo, pero cuando intento conectarme me tira el siguiente error, en esta linea.

```
        var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DefaultConnection");

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
        connection.Open(); <-- justo aquí
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - No se puede ubicar la instalación de Local Database Runtime. Compruebe que SQL Server Express se ha instalado correctamente y que se ha habilitado la característica de tiempo de ejecución de la base de datos local.)'

esta es la cadena de conexión que recibe mi variable

> "Data Source=CENCS-162\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DemoFSWebApp;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"

Y si, ya chequé que mi bd, si existe en **MSSMS**

Pero ahora me manda este error :

> ok ya probé pero ahora me da este error > System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error de instancia.' ahora subo mis cambios a la pregunta

Comment: Estás seguro de que si llega el connection string a tu variable de entorno?. Ponle un Console.WriteLine(connectionString) antes del open y valida si llega.

Comment: si, si me llega, ahora agrego lo que recibo de ella.

Comment: ¿No te hace falta Initial Catalog?

Comment: En la cadena de conexión solo indicas la instancia del servidor pero no indicas ah que db te vas a conectar ni el usuario ni contraseña

Comment: El datasource de la imagen es diferente al datasource que muestra tu connection string. es a proposito?

Comment: @gbianchi si es a proposito, solo cambie el verdadero nombre de mi pc por "mipc", pero fuera de eso todo esta igual

Comment: @vcasas como me quedría si mi user es "sa" y mi pass "pass123!A" ???

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim revisa la respuesta que te deje. Si te sirve puedes marcarla para que pueda ayudar a otros a futuro. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que presentas básicamente es por tu `connectionString` en el cual estas omitiendo los principales datos para establecer una conexión con tu `data base`. Te dejo dos conexiones que deberían resolver tu problema. (debes cambiar los valores por los tuyos).

```
Data Source=instanciaSQL;Initial Catalog=dataBase;Integrated Security=True
```

o

```
Data Source=instanciaSQL;Initial Catalog=dataBase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=usuarioDB;Password=passwordDB
```

- Data Source: instancia del servidor SQL
- Initial Catalog: nombre de la DB
- User ID: nombre de usuario del servidor SQL
- Password: contraseña del usuario del servidor SQL

Comment: tengo una pregunta, la cuestión es que ese string no me lo armé yo, si no que es el que crea el proyecto cuando lo conecto por el asistente  SQL en VS, no debería entrar sin problemas?

Comment: Si correcto, te debe haber creado un localdb y por eso tu connectionString es más corto que el segundo que te deje en el ejemplo. Pero quizás te falto asignar la db ya que sin el Initial Catalog muy dificll o mejor dicho imposible que te conectes a la db.

Comment: ok ya probé pero ahora me da este error > System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error de instancia.' ahora subo mis cambios a la pregunta

Comment: Y si pruebas tu cadena de conexión sin el doble \, solo con uno? mira guíate por estos casos similares que ocurrió el mismo error.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650482/instance-failure-error-while-connection-string-is-correct
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675202/sql-server-connect-error-instance-failure
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830824/instance-failure-in-asp-net

Comment: pues funcionó, pero estuvo muy raro, en el appsettings.json si le quitaba una de las 2 \ me daba error, pero en mis variables de sesión , que es a la que llamo, le quite uno y pum listo query hecho.

Comment: Las variables de sesión serian tus variables de entorno ¿verdad? y pues claro en c# tienes que escapar el símbolo \ y para escaparlo se hace con doble backslash de lo contrario te dará error. Pero que bueno que te funciono ! (:

Comment: perdón de entorno, tienes toda la razón.

Answer (score 0):

Para conectar con la base de datos necesitas un connectionString, el cual está definido en el archivo appsettings.json mira este ejemplo:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionStringNombre": "Server=yourServer;Database=yourDatabase;Trusted_Connection=false;User ID=yourUser;Password=yourPassword"
  }
}
```

Luego que tienes configurado el connectionString debes instanciar el contexto (base de datos), esto lo puedes lograr de la siguiente forma:

En la clase Startup en el método`public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`

añade el contexto

```
        services.AddDbContext<ContextName>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration["ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringNombre"]);
        },
        ServiceLifetime.Scoped
        );
```

donde ContextName es el nombre de la clase que hereda de DbContext (este ejemplo utiliza EF Core)

Luego cuando necesites obtener datos desde tu bd lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma

```
        public async Task<dynamic> GetRequestAsync(int id)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            return await connection.QueryAsync<dynamic>(
                @"SELECT Id, FechaEmision, NumeroSeguimiento, UsuarioRut, SolicitudEstadoId
                FROM Solicitudes
                WHERE Id=@id",
                new { id }
                );
        }
    }
```

Donde `_connectionString` es un atributo de la clase que contiene el método `GetRequestAsync` cuyo valor es asignado a través de la DI que ofrece netcore

(recuerda que `IServiceCollection` es el IoC que contiene tus clases esperando ser instanciadas)

Este ejemplo también utiliza la librería Dapper la cual permite ejecutar la query con el método `QueryAsync`